# How to Allow Print button in Android Web-view Using Java?

Tags: java, android, pdf, printing, webview

How to Print a page in Web-view in Android Studio Using Java?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
<h3>Here is English, Spanish, Arabic, Hindi, Japanese, Korean and Assamese</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>I won't pretent to be the someone that I am not.</li>
            <li>No pretenderé ser el alguien que no soy.</li>
            <li>मैं वह होने का नाटक नहीं करूँगा जो मैं नहीं हूँ।</li>
            <li>私は自分ではない誰かのふりをするつもりはありません</li>
            <li>나는 내가 아닌 다른 사람인 척하지 않을 것입니다.</li>
        </ul>

    <button type="button" onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here how can we allow users to print the page in android web-view using only the **Print** button.

You can check this picture below what I actually mean

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJYey.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Create `assets` folder in project app folder and create file with .html extension and paste your code in that file. And call below code in `onCreate()` method of an Activity

```
 setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
 wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xyz.html");
```

Comment: I did not mean that. How to allow print button in Android webview